# No item with Given ID can be found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am having issues when running my script after the most recent API update. I had some issues that I was able to fix with some help from around here but now I am having a get by ID issue. I am unsure of where it is coming from because I have a few things that get by ID. Any help? Here is my code if you want to run it and a picture of what the error looks like.

If you want to run it you need to have a folder called Templates and a document inside of there. Inside of the document just needs to be {A} for column A in your spreadsheet and it should still give you that error, thanks!

[image]

```
function generateDocument(e) {
        var template = DriveApp.getFileById(e.parameter.Templates);
        Logger.log(template.getName());
        var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var row = Number(e.parameter.row) //+1; // Remove the // in this line next to the +1 to skip headers
        Logger.log(row);
        var currentFID = e.parameter.curFID;
        Logger.log(currentFID);
        var myDocID = template.makeCopy(Sheet.getRange('B' + row).getValue() + ' - ' + Sheet.getRange('E' + row).getValue() + ' - ' + Sheet.getRange('D' + row).getValue() + ' - ' + Sheet.getRange('X' + row).getValue()).getId();
        var myDoc = DocumentApp.openById(myDocID);
        var copyBody = myDoc.getActiveSection();
        var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        //row--; // decrement row number to be in concordance with real row numbers in sheet
        var myRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(row + ":" + row);
        for (var i = 1; i < Sheet.getLastColumn() + 1; i++) {
            var myCell = myRow.getCell(1, i);
            copyBody.replaceText("{" + myCell.getA1Notation().replace(row, "") + "}", myCell.getValue());
        }
        myDoc.saveAndClose();
        var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(currentFID);
        Logger.log(myDocID);
        var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(myDocID); // get the document again but using DriveApp this time...
        doc.addToFolder(destFolder); // add it to the desired folder
        doc.removeFromFolder(DriveApp.getRootFolder()); // I did it step by step to be more easy to follow
        var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(myDocID).getAs("application/pdf");
        destFolder.createFile(pdf); // this will create the pdf file in your folder
        var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
        app.close();
        return app;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function getTemplates() {
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Generate from template');
        // Create a grid with 3 text boxes and corresponding labels
        var grid = app.createGrid(5, 2);
        grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Template name:'));
        var list = app.createListBox();
        list.setName('Templates');
        grid.setWidget(0, 1, list);

        var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Templates");
        while (folders.hasNext()) 
        {
          var folder = folders.next();
          Logger.log(folder.getName());
          var allMyFilesByType = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)
        };
        while (allMyFilesByType.hasNext())
        {
          var file = allMyFilesByType.next();
          list.addItem(file.getName());
          Logger.log(file.getName());
        };

        grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Row:'));
        var row = app.createTextBox().setName('row');
        row.setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getRow());
        grid.setWidget(1, 1, row);
        var curFN = app.createTextBox().setText('MyDrive/').setName('curFN').setId('curFN').setWidth('400');
        var curFID = app.createTextBox().setText(DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId()).setName('curFID').setId('curFID').setVisible(false);
        var listF = app.createListBox().setName('listF').setId('listF').addItem('Please Select Folder', 'x');
        grid.setText(2, 0, 'Type Path:').setWidget(2, 1, curFN).setText(3, 0, 'OR').setText(4, 0, 'Choose Path:').setWidget(4, 1, listF).setWidget(3, 1, curFID);
        var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFolders();
        while (folders.hasNext()) {
            var folder = folders.next();
            listF.addItem(folder.getName(),folder.getId())
        };
        var handlerF = app.createServerHandler('folderSelect').addCallbackElement(grid);
        listF.addChangeHandler(handlerF);
        var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
        panel.add(grid);
        var button = app.createButton('Submit');
        var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('generateDocument');
        handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
        button.addClickHandler(handler);
        // Add the button to the panel and the panel to the application, then display the application app in the Spreadsheet doc
        panel.add(button);
        app.add(panel);
        doc.show(app);
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function folderSelect(e) 
{
        var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
        var currentFN = e.parameter.curFN;
        var currentFID = e.parameter.listF;
        Logger.log(currentFID);
        var listF = app.getElementById('listF');
        var curFN = app.getElementById('curFN');
        var curFID = app.getElementById('curFID');
        if (currentFID == 'x') {
            currentFID = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId();
            curFN.setText('MyDrive/')
        };
        var startFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(currentFID);
        var folders = startFolder.getFolders();
        listF.clear().addItem('No More Sub Folders!', 'x').addItem('Go back to Root', 'x');
        if (folders.length > 0) {
            listF.clear();
            listF.addItem('Select Sub Folder', 'x')
        };
        while (folders.hasNext()) {
            var folder = folders.next();
            listF.addItem(folder.getName(),folder.getId())
        };
        curFN.setText(currentFN + DriveApp.getFolderById(currentFID).getName() + '/');
        if (currentFID == DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId()) {
            curFN.setText('MyDrive/')
        };
        curFID.setText(currentFID);
        return app;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [{
        name: "Export Row to Document",
        functionName: "getTemplates"
    }];
    ss.addMenu("Generate Documents Here!", menuEntries);
}
```

Comment: You could debug your code you know? If you don't see the line error, make line breaks, click on the number and it will set a red dot, this will stop the code there when debugging, or surround some parts of the code with TryCatch.

Comment: Sorry I am not that great with Java script, only know if from working with these scripts I didn't know you could do that. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is in this statement

> var template = DriveApp.getFileById(e.parameter.Templates);

when you see the e.parameter.Templates name in logger it will be a file name. but DriveApp.getFileById will expect file id.

the above problem can be solved when you add file Id along with file name in

> list.addItem(file.getName(),file.getId());

of getTemplates()  method.

here is working code

```
function generateDocument(e) 
{
        //Logger.log(DriveApp.getFilesByName(e.parameter.Templates).);
        //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e.parameter.Templates);
        var template = DriveApp.getFileById(e.parameter.Templates);
        //Logger.log(e.parameter.Templates.getId());
        var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var row = Number(e.parameter.row) //+1; // Remove the // in this line next to the +1 to skip headers
        Logger.log(row);
        var currentFID = e.parameter.listF;
        Logger.log(currentFID);
        var myDocID = template.makeCopy(Sheet.getRange('B' + row).getValue() + ' - ' + Sheet.getRange('E' + row).getValue() + ' - ' + Sheet.getRange('D' + row).getValue() + ' - ' + Sheet.getRange('X' + row).getValue()).getId();
        var myDoc = DocumentApp.openById(myDocID);
        var copyBody = myDoc.getActiveSection();
        var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        //row--; // decrement row number to be in concordance with real row numbers in sheet
        var myRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(row + ":" + row);
        for (var i = 1; i < Sheet.getLastColumn() + 1; i++) {
            var myCell = myRow.getCell(1, i);
            copyBody.replaceText("{" + myCell.getA1Notation().replace(row, "") + "}", myCell.getValue());
        }
        myDoc.saveAndClose();
        var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(currentFID);
        Logger.log(myDocID);
        var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(myDocID); // get the document again but using DriveApp this time...

        destFolder.addFile(doc);//add to filder
        var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(myDocID).getAs("application/pdf");
        destFolder.createFile(pdf); // this will create the pdf file in your folder
        var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
        app.close();
        return app;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function getTemplates() 
{
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Generate from template');
        // Create a grid with 3 text boxes and corresponding labels
        var grid = app.createGrid(5, 2);
        grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Template name:'));
        var list = app.createListBox();
        list.setName('Templates');
        grid.setWidget(0, 1, list);

        var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Templates");
        while (folders.hasNext()) 
        {
          var folder = folders.next();
          Logger.log(folder.getName());
          var allMyFilesByType = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)
        };
        while (allMyFilesByType.hasNext())
        {
          var file = allMyFilesByType.next();
          list.addItem(file.getName(),file.getId());
          Logger.log(file.getName());
        };

        grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Row:'));
        var row = app.createTextBox().setName('row');
        row.setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getRow());
        grid.setWidget(1, 1, row);
        var curFN = app.createTextBox().setText('MyDrive/').setName('curFN').setId('curFN').setWidth('400');
        var curFID = app.createTextBox().setText(DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId()).setName('curFID').setId('curFID').setVisible(false);
        var listF = app.createListBox().setName('listF').setId('listF').addItem('Please Select Folder', 'x');
        grid.setText(2, 0, 'Type Path:').setWidget(2, 1, curFN).setText(3, 0, 'OR').setText(4, 0, 'Choose Path:').setWidget(4, 1, listF).setWidget(3, 1, curFID);
        var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFolders();
        while (folders.hasNext()) {
            var folder = folders.next();
            listF.addItem(folder.getName(),folder.getId())
        };
        var handlerF = app.createServerHandler('folderSelect').addCallbackElement(grid);
        listF.addChangeHandler(handlerF);
        var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
        panel.add(grid);
        var button = app.createButton('Submit');
        var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('generateDocument');
        handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
        button.addClickHandler(handler);
        // Add the button to the panel and the panel to the application, then display the application app in the Spreadsheet doc
        panel.add(button);
        app.add(panel);
        doc.show(app);
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function folderSelect(e) 
{
        var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
        var currentFN = e.parameter.curFN;
        var currentFID = e.parameter.listF;
        Logger.log(currentFID);
        var listF = app.getElementById('listF');
        var curFN = app.getElementById('curFN');
        var curFID = app.getElementById('curFID');
        if (currentFID == 'x') {
            currentFID = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId();
            curFN.setText('MyDrive/')
        };
        var startFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(currentFID);
        var folders = startFolder.getFolders();
        listF.clear().addItem('No More Sub Folders!', 'x').addItem('Go back to Root', 'x');
        if (folders.length > 0)
        {
            listF.clear();
            listF.addItem('Select Sub Folder', 'x')
        };
        while (folders.hasNext()) 
        {
            var folder = folders.next();
            listF.addItem(folder.getName(),folder.getId())
        };
        curFN.setText(currentFN + DriveApp.getFolderById(currentFID).getName() + '/');
        if (currentFID == DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId()) {
            curFN.setText('MyDrive/')
        };
        curFID.setText(currentFID);
        return app;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function onOpen() 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [{
        name: "Export Row to Document",
        functionName: "getTemplates"
    }];
    ss.addMenu("Generate Documents Here!", menuEntries);
}
```

Comment: I still get a no ID given but it does actually make the document but it puts it in the wrong folder? I am going to try and figure it out, just wanted to let you know.

Comment: sorry for that i also changed this statement  var currentFID = e.parameter.curFID; to var currentFID = e.parameter.listF; and also delete this line SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(destFolder.getName);